# Can't add Connected Service to a MVC Project targeting .Net 4.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-office, preview, office365

I'm trying to get started with a MVC project that consumes the Office 365 API. I have a MVC project targeting .Net 4.5.1 ready. When I try to add a Connected Service, I can't seem to find that option in Visual Studio.

[image]

The extension is installed and I've restarted VS, as mentioned.

[image]

I've tried the same with a Windows Store App for Windows 8.1 and got the same result.

Comment: @VahidND I've tried that, Add New Item -> Searched all installed templates, still no luck :(

Comment: Have you installed [Office 365 API Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7e947621-ef93-4de7-93d3-d796c43ba34f)

Comment: Yes, I have, please see the screen that I've added to the question

Comment: Hi did u find a solution

Comment: @shiba yes I found a solution, apparently you need to be working on VS 2013/2015. 2012 does not have support for Connected Service to be added to an MVC solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to a similar question under the [Office 365 API Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7e947621-ef93-4de7-93d3-d796c43ba34f) page's "Q and A" section provide by [Michael Zlatkovsky (MSFT)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/michael%20zlatkovsky%20%28msft%29/?ws=usercard-hover), he suggests:

> 1. Close Visual Studio 2013
> 2. In Windows Explorer, navigate to C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\
> 3. There should be a list of folders there, with names like "qsn5xrd4.5al" (each installation will have different names).  Find
>      the folder that has "Microsoft.Office365ApiTools.dll" within it.
> 4. Once you've identified the correct folder, find the file "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Contracts.dll", and either
>      delete, move, or rename it.  This particular file is not needed for
>      the add-in to run, but its presence can cause the issue on certain
>      machine configurations.
> 5. Re-open Visual Studio and try again.

and in case it didn't solved the problem:

> try deleting 
>   "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache"
>   (I would recommend moving it to the desktop or otherwise making a
>   backup, just in case). This should flush the cache, and force VS to
>   re-load the add-in -- now with loading
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Contracts.dll" from its
>   central location.

Comment: Thanks, the discussion helped a lot, I face another problem now though, I can only add Connected Service to a Windows Store App and can't find the option for a MVC Web Application.

Comment: is there any way to add connected services in VS2012?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis, unfortunately this feature is only in VS 2013 and VS 2015.